# Why can't I remove a CSS class from my HTML element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

My goal is, when user pass my first `section(#video-section)`, I want to close my side menu.

This is my code:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById("video-section");
    var menubar = document.getElementsByClassName("menubar");
    var drawer = document.getElementsByClassName("drawer");

    var videoheight = video.offsetHeight;
    console.log("Scroll amount:" + window.pageYOffset);
    console.log("Video section amount:" + videoheight)

    if (window.pageYOffset == videoheight) {
        console.log("Passed");
        menubar.classList.remove("open");
    }
};
```

I get the following error message at the `classList.remove()` function call:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at window.onscroll

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) Which doesn't have a property called `classList`, so it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`getElementsByClassName()`** returns an array of nodes and not a single node.

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns an array of all the nodes that contain that particular class provided as a string in its parameter. You can do the following to make it correct:

1. Provide an `id` attribute to your menubar and use `getElementById` to get that particular node.
2. Or, do `menubar[0].classList.remove("open");` to remove the class from the first matched element node.

Comment: It returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an Array.

Comment: Who are you quoting?

Answer (score 0):

well because the `menubar` is not an object but an `HTMLCollection`
and `classList` for that is `undefined`
heres what you can do:
`var menubar = document.querySelector('.menubar');`
which then you would be able to change it's `style` and `classList` of.
hope it works well for you:)

Comment: But it _is_ an object. `HTMLCollection`s are objects, too.

Comment: aw right, but what I meant was she can serve the purpose by `document.querySelector`, to change the `classList`

Answer (score 0):

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a read only property that exists on an element itself and not on the result of getElementsByClassName method, which is a collection .